# bitcoind 0.8.4 is having huge memory leak causing daemon to crash

Tags: memory-leaks, crash, bitcoin

We have ubuntu 12.04 and bitcoin 0.8.4. We have used these same version previously for setting up many bitcoin based servers and websites. But recently when creating new server with these versions of ubuntu and bitcoin, I am seeing huge memory consumption by bitcoind. I see virtual memory is approaching around 1.6 G before crashing the daemon. And it happens quite fast within 1/2 hr or so.  There is definitely some memory leak, but I am not running anything at the on server and not even interacting with bitcoind. bitcoind is being started on a freshly build ubuntu server. Is anyone else seeing this issue?

I have tried setting up maxCLient with no effect. Have tried increasing the swap space, which made bicoind run longer, but still crashed later on as memory leak is continuously growing.

Any help or clue appreciated.

Thanks,
-Arvind

Answer (score 1):

This probably isn't a memory leak. Bitcoind will utilize high memory/CPU while the blockchain is being downloaded and processed. I've also noticed frequent crashing on AWS micro/small EC2 instances while the blockchain is being processed.

In my experience, once your local copy of the blockchain is up-to-date you shouldn't have issues with high CPU/memory usage. For now you could consider setting up a cron task that will reboot bitcoind in the event of a crash. Something like this should work:

```
* * * * * (pgrep bitcoind > /dev/null) || /usr/local/bin/bitcoind --daemon
```

Good luck.